# How do I get git manual entries?

Tags: git

I downloaded Git source and installed it in a non-standard path. All the Git options have a `-h` option but the documentation listed there is very terse and many options are missing. I'd like the full documentation but am unable to find it. When I run `git help log` or `git log --help` I get the following error:

```
No manual entry for git-log
```

I've tried adding every path imaginable to `PATH` and `MANPATH` but it does no good, I still get these pesky errors. How can I get `git <option> --help` to work?

Comment: This depends entirely on where you installed Git to. Why are you installing it to a non-standard path anyway?

Comment: That's really not relevant but since you are curious I've installed it on an NFS mount so it's available from all the machines on my network. Also, I don't have root access to all those machines and they are running ancient OSes (RHEL4) with crummy package managers with access to old software, which can't be changed. Just assume path is <path> to answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: What command did you use to build and install? The answer to your question really depends on what your build command was.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git's manpages are (for some reason) a completely separate download from the actual source code, and are thus not installed when compiling and installing from source.

You can find the manpages for each release in [git-core's downloads list](https://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list).

Comment: I never would have thought! This is the first project that I've come across like that. Anyway, I've added them in the right spot and it now works. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think the manpages are sort of included in the source, but you actually have to compile them to and it adds a significant amount of time and complexity to the build process so they offer them separately already compiled.

Comment: dead link, [git-core/downloads/list](http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list) shows man and html too

Comment: The manpages are available at that link, but the documentation is part of the repo.  I think all distros now ship with make target tab completion, so just type `make install<Tab>` and select your format, {-doc,-man,-pdf,-html,-info}

Comment: And one can untar these downloaded doc-tar in any folder. And simply set MANPATH environment-variable to point to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you can install manual pages with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-man
```

Comment: While this might work, you will then have the binary version typically different from the documentation. In same cases, this can be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

get manpage here git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-manpages.git
then copy then to you system,like /usr/local/share/man/

Answer (score 1):

Lately, if you get `Git` from the git repository at https://github.com/git (what a mind meddling), you will also get the documentation. Then you just have to install it.

On Ubuntu, you need to have `asciidoc` and `xmlto` installed, then you can simply

```
make prefix=if-you-change-binary-prefix install-doc
```

You should then be able to use man pages.

Answer (score -4):

try

```
 man git log
```

I get the man info use above command.I also did not get man info use the command you used.

Comment: This might be among the worst answers I have seen. Please find your way to a DPRK gulag.

Comment: I'll sacrifice a reputation point to downvote this answer as well.  The accepted answer (as well as from my understanding) stated that the help files are not installed and compiled when installing from source, so doing this will not allow you to access the manpage for git-log.