# No manual entry for giteveryday

Tags: linux, git

I installed git using

`_sudo apt-get install git_`

But `git help everyday` gives following error:

> No manual entry for giteveryday

Even though, this appears similar to one [How do I get git manual entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674351/how-do-i-get-git-manual-entries)
I feel this is different.
`git-man` is already installed and `git help <command>` works for all commands except **giteveryday**.
I don't know why this is happening?? Am I missing something??

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674351/how-do-i-get-git-manual-entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have downloaded git from a source and ended up not having the ***git manpages***.
You can download those and then try your command :

```
sudo apt-get install git-man
```

Manual download source is [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-core/downloads).

***Edit*** : As suggested by @ElpieKay in Ubuntu the same command goes as :

```
sudo apt-get install git-doc
```

Comment: **git-manpages** is already installed and still getting the error

Comment: @Munendra Sorry, in Windows it's okay. I tried in Ubuntu, and got the same error. After `sudo apt-get install git-doc` is done, the html and txt docs can be found at /usr/share/doc/git-doc

Comment: @ElpieKay, Could you please specify the **git version**. My git version 1.9.1

Comment: @ElpieKay That Error was raised because I was using older version(1.9.1)  
I upgraded git to its newer verion(2.8.2) . It works now. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If Git is installed, you can always run `git --html-path` to see where the html docs are. You can find the link to `giteveryday` in the index.html.

Also you can read it [online](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I tried your suggestion. It generated following error. I am posting a screenshot of the same.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTol5a23wd-ejZST09raFpiX3M/view?usp=sharing